# Solution of sum

Tags: summation

What is an easy way to find the solution of this sum?

$$\displaystyle\sum_{i=1}^{\infty} i3\Bigg(\frac{1}{3}\Bigg)^{i+1}$$

wolframalpha solution: $\frac{3}{4}$

Comment: Roll a pair of dice, one after the other, and put the result of the first toss of a die in the numerator, and the result of the second toss of the die in the denominator.  Looks like WA rolled first a three, then a four.

Comment: Hint: differentiate the series for $\frac{1}{1-x}$.

Comment: this serie is completely weird $\displaystyle\sum_{i=1}^{\infty} i3\Bigg(\frac{1}{3}\Bigg)^{i+1}=\displaystyle\sum_{i=1}^{\infty} i\Bigg(\frac{1}{3}\Bigg)^{i}$

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Somewhat more generally, if $|r| < 1$ $$\sum_{i=1}^\infty a i r^i = r \frac{d}{dr} \sum_{i=1}^\infty a r^i$$
Now use the formula for geometric series.

Comment: but starting from $i=1$

Comment: Starting from either $1$ or $0$: $i=0$ doesn't contribute.